# react native - react context like icon action

Tags: react-native

I am currently storing my user using react context, each user can like as many posts as they want.

i have a parameter called isLiked in my backend that can either be true or false for each post for each user.

Here is my code:

I attempted a solution, my problem is that when i press the outlined heart to like a post it changes to a heart and a record of this like is sorted in my database but when i close the post and open it again it does not change, i need to refresh app in order for it to change.

attempted solution

Postdetailsscreen.js

```
const post=route.params;

  const [addedToLikes, setAddedToLikes] = useState(post.isLiked);

 const addToLikes = (PostId,userId) => {
  setAddedToLikes(!addedToLikes);
  likePost({PostId,userId});
  };


 <TouchableOpacity
 onPress={() => {
 addToLikes(post.id,user.id);
  }}
              >
{addedToLikes ? 
   <MaterialCommunityIcons
     name="heart"
      />
   : 
    <MaterialCommunityIcons
    name="heart-outline"
     />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

in my backend i have an isLiked parameter that if the current userId and postId are found in my likes table then isLiked is true otherwise false.

here is my backend code:-

```
 router.get("/",
 auth,
  async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post.findAll({
order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
include: [
  { model: User, attributes: ["id", "name", "email"] },
  { model: Post_Image, attributes: ["id", "images"] },
 ]})

  if (!posts) return res.status(404).send();

 const baseUrl = config.get("assetsBaseUrl");

 const plainPosts = posts.map((x) => x.get({ plain: true }));
const resultPosts = [];
 for (const post of plainPosts) {

  const isLiked = post.Likes.some(x => x.userId === req.user.id); 

  const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = listing;
   const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
  url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
  thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
}));
resultPosts.push({ ...postAttributes, images: IMAGES
  ,isLiked 
});
}

 res.send(resultPosts);
});
```

Can someone help me with that if a user liked a post the icon stays filled even without refreshing the app?

Comment: when restarting the app, your are initialising the app's like state with false `useState(false);` instead of initializing it will backend response whether the post is liked or not

Comment: @warl0ck so i should initialize it to something like this useState(isLiked=false)? But also when i like a post and it changes when i close the post and open it again it is not changed, i need to restart the app for it to change

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the props from parent component.

```
const Heart = ({ isLiked }) => {
         
         const [ liked, setLiked ] = useState(false);
       
         useEffect(() => {
             setLiked(isLiked)
         },[isLiked])

         ......
}
```

use useEffect to make sure you update your state whenever the isLiked prop changes.

Then in your parents component.

```
const ListofPost = () => {

     const data = fetchTheData(url);
     ....


     return ( data.map( item => <Heart isLiked={item.isLiked} />) )
}
```

Comment: i am actually getting my isLiked parameter from my backend.

Comment: const post = route.params;  console.log(post); when i press on a post to open it, the console.log is triggered and in console i see all information about the post. To access the isLiked parameter from backend i do post.isLiked

Comment: if u use route.params it means you pass your parameter from your parent. So if you pass parameter from parent you need to update your local state.

Comment: yes, i am actually passing route as a prop, so i should follow the solution you have provided but instead of isLiked in useEffect i use post.isLiked?

Comment: I tried doing it when i open an unliked post and like it the heart changes outlined to filled, but when i close the post and open the same post again without refreshing the heart is still outlined. But when i refresh the app, and open the same post the heart becomes filled.

Comment: try const [ isLiked, setIsLiked ]. = useState(post.isLiked)

Comment: i have updated my question with how i am getting my posts in backend, if you can please have a look'

Comment: i think i noticed where my problem is when i open an unliked post and like it, a record of that like is stored in my database but the application does not refresh hence it is not fetching the updated records from my database

Comment: const [addedToLikes, setAddedToLikes] = useState(post.isLiked); <- can u use the isLiked value as the initial value instead of props.

Comment: i tried it now, when i press the heart it changes to filled and in my backend i see a record of that like but the isLiked parameter does not change from false to true until i refresh the app, i think thats why when i close my post and open again without refreshing it is still using the old isLiked value

Comment: after you save the record, you need fetch the results again then update the state in the parent component. Your problem is due to you not refreshing the results after you save your database.

Comment: is that supposed to be done on frontend or backend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224950/discussion-between-someone-special-and-kd12345).

Comment: Hi, can we continue our discussion?